# How to Specify Line Number to write to in a file in Java

Tags: java

I am making a save function for my application and I am having an issue in which all my variables are writing to the same line. How can I select which line to write to in my writing section?

```
public static void save() throws IOException {
    String savecps = String.valueOf(cps);
    String savecpscost = String.valueOf(cpscost);
    String savecw = String.valueOf(cw);
    String savecwcost = String.valueOf(cwcost);
    String saveceo = String.valueOf(ceo);
    String saveceocost = String.valueOf(ceocost);

    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), savecps.getBytes());
    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), savecpscost.getBytes());
    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), savecw.getBytes());
    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), savecwcost.getBytes());
    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), saveceo.getBytes());
    Files.write(Paths.get("Vars"), saveceocost.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: How should java know that all that stuff does not beong in the same line? You have to add linebraks yourself.

Comment: Ok... How do you add a line break in a file in this manner? (I am assuming that you meant line break.)

Comment: *"How do you add a line break in a file in this manner"* as usual: +"\n"

Comment: Or you combine a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) with a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and then use `PrintWriter::println(String)`.